# Stuck in an infinite loop of input C++

Tags: c++

I'm kind of a newbie in C++ so go easy on me, i can't seem to figure out what's the issue here.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    int max = a;
    int nums[] = {a, b, c, d};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if(nums[i] > nums[i--])
        {
            max = nums[i];
        }
        else
        {
            ;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
}
```

All it does is ask for input but doesn't do anything else!
Any help would be appreciated!
PS: it's supposed to take 4 numbers and return the biggest one.

Comment: `nums[i--]`? Try `nums[i-1]` instead.

Comment: *All it does is ask for input but doesn't do anything else* That's all you've told it to do.  If you want it to print something, you need a `cout` statement

Comment: Are you using an IDE? IF so you can use a debugger

Comment: Isn't this better suited for codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Tara This is not working code.

Comment: Return in what way? Do you mean output? There's no code here to produce output.

Comment: You have a bug.  The for-loop increments the control variable i (i++) but inside the loop you decrement it (i--); the net effect being i(starting at 0)-1+1-1+1..., never reaching 4 (first decrement is before first increment).  To fix, try iterating `for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)` and comparing `nums[i] > nums[i - 1]`.

Comment: `if(cin >> a >> b >> c >> d) cout << max_of_four(a, b, c, d) << "\n";`

Comment: @AlanK All the answers below have pointed that out already and comparing `nums[i] > nums[i - 1]` won't give the correct answer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ah, sorry. Wasn't aware of that rule.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: First time I've seen the other answers, not sure I would have bothered otherwise, I was having a "first attempt at helping clear the First Posts" queue.  As for the code change I suggested, give it a try, not pretty but... well the intention is that the OP learns to visualise right?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this line `if(nums[i] > nums[i--])` causing the loop to never end.
Even when you fix it with `if(nums[i] > nums[i-1])` your logic is wrong because it does not return the maximum element.

Consider the following 4 integers:

```
a=1, b=4 c=1,d=2
```

Your code will return  `2` while the maximum element is `4`

Try with something like the following:

```cpp
        max = nums[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if(nums[i] > max) //issue here

            {
                max = nums[i];
            }
        }
```

---

and since you are in C++, while not using `std::max_element`?
Simply do:

```cpp
       int nums[] = {a, b, c, d};
       return *(std::max_element(nums, nums+4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop increases `i` by one with `i++`, and then your array operator decreases it by one with `i--`. Thus `i` never changes, and the loop never ends.

```cpp
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if(nums[i] > nums[i--])
//                        ^^^ here's your issue
        {
            max = nums[i];
        }
        else
        {
            ;
        }
    }
```

Were you trying to access the element one slot before `i`? If so, you'll need to do `nums[i-1]`. Be careful, though: if `i` is 0, this will go out of the array's bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop because within the loop the index i is decremented

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                      ^^^
{
    if(nums[i] > nums[i--])
                      ^^^^
    {
        max = nums[i];
    }
    // ...
```

and then in the for statement in the third expression is incremented

Also there is no need to use a loop because there is already standard function `std::max` declared in the header `<algorithm>`.

You could just write

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return std::max( { a, b, c, d } );
}
```

and in main you could output the value

```
std::cout << "The maximum value is " << max_of_four( a, b, c, d ) << '\n';
```